# When to use camera calibration in object detection?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, camera-calibration, yolov5

I am trying to find the realistic location of an object using yolov5. but idk if I should use OpenCV camera calibration before running detect.py or use it after the model gave me center x and center y of the detected object. if I need to use camera calibration after detection then what function do I have to use?

[Result without camera calibration] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLrLB.jpg)
the image on the right is an output of my model. I am focus on the object with details shown in the last line of the text file on the left. since my camera didn't take the image right above these objects then the results.txt shouldn't give the exact location.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?  What would you expect calibration to provide?

Comment: I'm using a robot to do pick and place these objects. I think my current result didn't give me the exact location for my robot to pick these objects since the image I captured was a trapezoid. I'm expecting calibration can somehow convert the location in the image into the location in real life.

Comment: You need to calibrate your field of view before you start.  The OpenCV documentation describes the process, using something like a chessboard.